# Oracle database query throws error on second run

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, odbc

i have an VBA code where i am calling oracle to retrieve data twice using ODBC.
First data retrieval is fine. But 2nd time it is saying ,

```
**RunTime Error '-2147467259 (80004005)'; Unspecified error**
```

My Code is as follows,

> Note: Same code works for connecting Teradata but failed when i use
>   Oracle

```
'First Data retrieval
Query1 = "Select TableName from all_tables"
CmdSQLData.CommandText = Query1
CmdSQLData.CommandType = adcmdText 
CmdSQLData.Timeout=0
set rs = CmdSQLData.Execute()
'Then code to store data ...
'This part gives proper result ...
rs.close()

'Second Data retrieval
Query2 = "Select * from db.Event"
CmdSQLData.CommandText = Query2
CmdSQLData.CommandType = adcmdText 
CmdSQLData.Timeout=0
set rs = CmdSQLData.Execute() 'This line Gives Error - RunTime Error '-2147467259 (80004005)'; Unspecified error
```

> Also i tried creating new command object as cmdSQLData1 but still same
>   error

May i know why the error is coming for second query ?
There is no problem with query as i have tested in oracle directory.
Please let me know

Comment: Please do not put keywords into question titles. That is what tags are for. Question titles should only include keywords if they can be used organically, not shoehorned into the beginning (or end) of a question. Let's not get into an edit war. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10651/147645 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see this documented much of anywhere, but reusing `Command` objects with different comamndText is actually a bad practice. You don't say what kind of connection you're using, but for example if it's ODBC, this will internally send a fake invalid SQL to Oracle to force a cleanup of some kind. So instead, throw away your `Command` object after use and create a new one.

Reusing `Command` objects is a *good* practice when you're re-executing the same query with different parameter values, but that's not the case here.

Comment: then how come the similar code works for connecting teradata ?

Comment: i tried creating new command object as cmdSQLData1 but still same error.

Comment: Can you post your updated code, including the initialization of the `Command` object? Also, how are you creating your `Connection`?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use command text at all for those types of queries what you could do is :-

`    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

```
con.Open "DSN=Oracle", "User", "Password"
rs.Open "select * from table_a", con

' Read all results

rs.Close

rs.Open "select * from table_b", con
' Read all results

rs.Close

con.Close
```

You only need to use "Command" if you plan to use a store procedure or a query with bound parameters.