# vba ODBC gives Unspecified error when oracle table is having timestamp

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, odbc

I have vba code to fetch Oracle tables data in to a recordset via **ODBC**. But it shows some unspecified error if the oracle table is having timestamp field in it.

I have 100+ table i dont know which table will have timestamp. 
I am running below query in loop to retrieve data.

```
Query = "Select End_Time from MyTable" 'this table has End_Time timestamp(6) field
CmdSQLData.CommandText = Query
CmdSQLData.CommandType = adcmdText  
CmdSQLData.Timeout=0 set rs = CmdSQLData.Execute() 'This line shows unspecified error then the table is having timestamp field 
'Then code for store data here...
```

> **RunTime Error '-2147467259 (80004005)'; Unspecified error**

Oracle Table structure is :

```
create table MyTable    (
Date_id Integer,
Date_Today Date,
End_Time Timestamp(6)
)
```

Please **do not suggest** some thing like,

> select to_char(timestamp_field) from my_table

**If i do above query, then the problem is not coming.**
I need permanent code to handle Timestamps in Recordsets because i may not know whether the table is having timestamp field or not as i have 100+ tables

Comment: I think you need to show exactly what you are doing. What is `Dynamic_table_name` for example? What is its structure? What does "Some time this table has timestamp(6) field" mean -- either it has that field or it doesn't. And you may need to mention which version of Oracle, too.

Comment: @AndrewLeach : i have modified the question to show specific example. Please let me know now.

Comment: You missed "What is its structure?" You need to give as much information as possible: no-one else can see what you can. Be our eyes and describe everything.

Comment: "Select TableName from Date_Time" won't work. Your table doesn't have a field called "TableName", and it doesn't have an "End_Time" field either.  Please post a working query with the actual structure of your table.

Comment: @HeadofCatering : Sorry, Now corrected. Please see and let me. i can not copy paste the code here becuase i am working on a server machine. I manually typed here.

Comment: Is it corrected? `Select TableName from MyTable` won't find anything because you don't have a field called `TableName`. Perhaps that's the reason it's failing.

Comment: How is this any different from the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11655114/190829)?

Comment: @HeadofCatering : the field is End_Time. Its corrected in question now. NOT WORKING in VB if the field is a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into something like the following: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4210331

Try upgrading your ODBC client.

Comment: i can not change the drivers as i am working at server machine.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me :-

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

con.Open "DSN=Oracle", "test", "test"
con.Execute "drop table tstest "
con.Execute "create table tstest ( a int, b Timestamp(6))"
con.Execute "insert into tstest values ( 1, current_timestamp ) "

q = "select * from tstest"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = q
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Debug.Print rs.Fields(1)

con.Close
```

This is using ADO 2.8 with Oracle driver version 11.1.0.7

*** NOTE : The Oracle driver comes from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) - you need to get it to work the :-

Instant Client Package - Basic
Instant Client Package - ODBC

You need both packages to get the driver to work. You then need to use an Instant Client connection in your ODBC data source for example :-

```
192.168.0.25:1521/orcl
```

IP:Port/Name

Comment: I am using Microsoft driver for oracle. I have that installed in my server machine. Please let me know