# Excel VBA ADO Recordset - Issue with SELECT columns

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I get

> Runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified Error

when I use the following code:

```
Set conn1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn1.Open strcon1
strquery3 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME"
Set rs3 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs3 = conn1.Execute(strquery3)
```

However the code works when I take lesser number of columns in my `SELECT` statement:

```
Set conn1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn1.Open strcon1
strquery3 = "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE_NAME"
Set rs3 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs3 = conn1.Execute(strquery3)
```

The table contains total 17 columns. Is there a restriction of number of columns? If not, is there any reason why I couldn't get all the 17 columns in my recordset?

I'm connecting to Oracle DB. Driver used - "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle"

Comment: There is no such limit in number of Columns. As you don't show the Connection String: Against what DB do you connect?. BTW: You can delete line 3: `Connection.Execute` creates a `Recordset`-object.

Comment: We need to know the data source. Also, can you return all fields(column) when you try retrieving it 1 by 1?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm connecting to Oracle DB.

Comment: @L42, I tried mentioning all the column names in the SELECT statement instead of SELECT *. It gave me the same error message.

Comment: Might be that one of the column names is clashing with a keyword? Starting with the 3, add a couple of columns at a time until it errors to narrow down which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Do you have by any change a field of type `TIMESTAMP`? There are some discussions about problems with this data type combined with some versions of Oracle driver, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671769/vba-odbc-gives-unspecified-error-when-oracle-table-is-having-timestamp

Comment: Yes, it works if I remove the two TIMESTAMP fields. I'm using "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver. Can I use any other driver and do the same thing ? I do need the timestamp fields in my output.

Comment: Yeah what I meant is 1 by 1 like `Select Colum1 From Table` until you figure out what field causes the error. But it seems you've found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cs As String
Dim sql As String


' Initialize objects
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

' Create connection string and query string
cs = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=<YOURSERVER>; Initial Catalog=<YOURDATABSE>; User ID=<YOURUSER>; Password=<YOURPASSWORD>"

sql = "select column1, column2 from table"

' Open connection and execute query
con.Open cs
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = sql

Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Then, you can access the column fields like:

```
Dim col1, col2 As String
col1 = rs.Fields("Column1").Value
col2 = rs.Fields("Column2").Value
```